# The first filename is preceded by a space

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, subprocess, file-rename

The names of all of them are changing properly, but the first file has a space in its name.

This my code:

```
import os

def dtr(x, y):

    os.chdir(str(x))
    c = os.listdir()

    c1 = str(c).replace(str(y), "")
    c_1 = c1.replace("[", "")
    c_2 = c_1.replace("]", "")
    c_3 = c_2.replace("'", "")
    c_dtr = c_3.split(",")


    x = 0
    while x < len(c):
        os.rename(c[x],c_dtr[x])
        x += 1 

dzn = input("Dizin: ")
dgtr = input("Değiştir: ")
dtr(dzn, dgtr)
input()
```

Comment: please provide sample input, obtained output and expected output.

Comment: Why are you making a single string from the list returned by `os.listdir()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the point in c* variables other than c itself in your example.

Can you try the following, ?

```
def dtr(x, y):
    c = os.listdir(str(x))

    for fname in c:
        os.rename(fname, fname.replace(str(y), ''))
```

As I understand, that would do what you want (rename the files/ folders in x path, removing string passed in y)

However, as I understand the community:

1. Try and describe what you are trying to do, not just what you're getting
2. Try and make your code language-independent